# Read & map data from Json file in c# test

Tags: c#, json, selenium, nunit, data-driven-tests

I was trying to use data from JSON file in automation test. Because I found how to work with it, thanks of @jeroenh I left here the correct way. I hope, it will help to somebody.

-- JSON file (testDataCo.Json):

```
{
  "DataCo": [
    {        
      "url": "https://dodo.com",
      "user": "test@test.com",
      "password": "uawe",       
    }
  ]
}
```

-- Class with data determination to JSON file

```
sing System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DataFromJson
{ 

    public partial class DataJson
    {
        [JsonProperty("DataCo")]
        public DataCo[] DataCo { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DataCo
    {       
        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }   

        [JsonProperty("user")]
        public string User { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }      
    }

    public partial class DataJson
    {
        public static DataJson FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataJson>(json, DataFromJson.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this DataJson self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, DataFromJson.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters = {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

-- Here you can use data from JSON in variables

```
public class UseJsonInVar
    {
       string filepath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../testDataCo.json"); 
       StreamReader ddd = new StreamReader(filepath);
       var json = ddd.ReadToEnd();
       DataJson objectJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataJson>(json);

       url = objectJson.DataCo[0].Url;
       user = objectJson.DataCo[0].User;
       pass = objectJson.DataCo[0].Password;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're reading the contents of your file into the variable `json`, but after that your code doesn't seem to do anything with it. An instance of `JsonData` is created, but the actual JSON data is never passed to it.

You'll need a library to deserialize the JSON data into an object. You're already using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which is a good one. With the library in your project references, you can do:

```
JsonData obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(json);
string plant = obj.plant; // "plant goco"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class has a root object, and the 'Dataco' field is an array.

You can easily convert json to the correct classes in Visual Studio using the 'Edit - Paste Special - Paste Json as Classes' function. Another possibility is using an online json-to-c# convertor, such as https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs

```
public partial class RootData
{
    [JsonProperty("DataCo")]
    public DataCo[] DataCo { get; set; }
}

public partial class DataCo
{
    [JsonProperty("discount")]
    public long Discount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quote name")]
    public string QuoteName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("base price")]
    public long BasePrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product description")]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("plant")]
    public string Plant { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("final price")]
    public long FinalPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quote id")]
    public string QuoteId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("freight")]
    public string Freight { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("billing price")]
    public long BillingPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public long Quantity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("proposed price")]
    public long ProposedPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("user")]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product id")]
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Given this class, you can deserialize the json text with `Newtonsoft JSON.Net`:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootData>(json);
```

Comment: I tried it and result is null. I don't understand why.
`DataCo obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataCo>(json);
                string plant = obj.Plant;
                Console.WriteLine(plant);`

Comment: finally I got it.. thanks of watcher in debug

    var json = r.ReadToEnd();  
    DataJson obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataJson>(json);  

    var plant = obj.DataCo[0].Plant;  
    Console.WriteLine(plant);

Comment: thank you very much, I updated the code and left the correct way here, I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you could make your json file embedded, consider using the package [JsonSectionReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WonderTools.JsonSectionReader/)

This package provides excellent support of unit testing with data in json.